# Threadsafe and exception catching events

Tags: c#, events

I have used the following example to excecute events:

```
try
{
    if (this.onClientConnected != null)
        this.onClientConnected(this, new EventArgs());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //log and handle exception
}
```

But of course this has some disadvantages like if one subscribed delegate throws an exception, the rest wont be executed and because I use it in multithreaded applications between checking for null and throwing the event someone can unsubscribe and a null exception will be thrown.

Now I looked at a better way to throw these events and come up with this:

```
Delegate[] methods = this.onClientConnected.GetInvocationList();
methods.ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    try
    {
        x.DynamicInvoke(this, new EventReceivedEventArgs(Trigger.TriggerName, Trigger.InstanceID, Trigger.Parameters, Trigger.SourceIpAddress));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //log and handle exception
    }
});
```

Is this a good way to do it or is there a better way to handle multithreaded events with exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to serialize all subscribtion/unsubscription logic, either by running all add/remove property accesses from the same thread, or by using locks at a correct abstraction level?  See [Stephen Toub's discussion on this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163533.aspx).

I would cache the multicast delegate out of the event into a local variable, check it, then "call" into it.  See [Eric Lippert's discussion on the topic.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx)

Consider wrapping events in Tasks, as [Igor Ostrovsky describes in this MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff959203.aspx).  Here's the TPL route...

For example (and I'm quoting):

```
static Task<string> DownloadStringAsTask(Uri address) {
  TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = 
    new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
  WebClient client = new WebClient();
  client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args) => {
    if (args.Error != null) tcs.SetException(args.Error);
    else if (args.Cancelled) tcs.SetCanceled();
    else tcs.SetResult(args.Result);
  };
  client.DownloadStringAsync(address);
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Exceptions can be observed wherever the returned Task is evaluated, for example with .Result or with .Wait().

Consider funneling event processing through the same thread.  For example, use .ContinueWith() overload that takes a scheduler that always posts to UI thread.

And finally, [Rx](https://rx.codeplex.com/) is another great alternative to events.